# Read columns from file where first row is string

Tags: python, numpy, scitools

What I would like to do is to read in columns from a `.dat` file. I have been able to do this using `scitools.filetable.read_columns()`. The problem that I am having is that the first row of my `.dat` file contains `strings`. How can I skip the first row?

So for a short example I have the following `.dat` file:

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   3   5   7   9
2   4   6   8  10
```

From this type of `.dat` file I want to create arrays for each column without the `string`. When the .dat file would not contain `a,b,c,d,e` it would be very easy as it would just be:

```
import scitools.filetable

fp = open("blabla.dat", "r")

a, b, c, d, e = scitools.filetable.read_columns(fp)
```

Now `a` would read: `[1  2]`.

However, when I try to do the same thing when `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are part of the `.dat` file, as indicated in my example, `scitools` does not work since it cannot convert a `string` to a `float`. How can I open the file without the first row or create the desired columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `fp.next` to advance one line further

As `fp` is file descriptor for file open in text mode, iterating over it reads it line by line.

You can ask `fp` to read one line further by `fp.next()` and then pass it to your `scitools.filetable.read_colums(fp)

Your code would look like this after modification:

```
import scitools.filetable

fp = open("blabla.dat", "r")
fp.next()

a, b, c, d, e = scitools.filetable.read_columns(fp)
```

Or using context manager for closing the file:

```
import scitools.filetable

with open("blabla.dat", "r") as fp:
    fp.next()

    a, b, c, d, e = scitools.filetable.read_columns(fp)
```